# Carousel en VB.net

Tags: html5, sql-server, bootstrap, vb.net

Estoy tratando de hacer un slider o carousel recuperando las rutas de las imágenes de mi base de datos a mi aplicacion de vb.net.

No logro mostrar las imágenes, además no puedo acceder a mis variables que están en el código HTML. Tanto `Response.Write(Indicators)` como `Response.Write(slides)` me aparecen subrayadas en color verde.

Estoy trabajando con una página maestra y mi código es el siguiente:

```
@Code
    PageData("Title") = "Escriba el título aquí"
    Layout = "_Layout.vbhtml"
    @Imports System.Data
    @Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    @Imports System.Data.Sql


    ' variables para carosuel ' 
    Dim slides As String
    Dim indicators As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    counter = 0

    Try

        Dim cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("portal").ConnectionString

        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conexion
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE status='1' ORDER BY datecreate "
        conexion.Open()       

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read()
                If counter = 0 Then
                    indicators="<li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='"& counter &"' class='active'></li>"
                    slides = "<div class='item active'><img src='" & dr.GetString(1) & "' /><div class='carousel-caption'><h3>" & dr.GetString(3) & "</h3></div></div>"
                Else
                    indicators = "<li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='" & counter & "'></li>"
                    slides = "<div class='item active'><img src='" & dr.GetString(1) & "' /><div class='carousel-caption'><h3>" & dr.GetString(3) & "</h3></div></div>"
                End If
                counter += 1
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox(":::error ::: ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Portal Fónix")
        End If
        dr.Close()
        conexion.Close()
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox(":::Hay una excepción::: " & exc.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Portal")
    End Try
End Code

<div> 
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page-inner">
            <section class="section-white">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicadores -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            @code
                                Response.Write(indicators)
                            End Code
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            @code
                                Response.Write(slides)
                            End Code
                        </div>
                        <!-- Controles -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no imprime lo que tiene mi variable indicator y slides en el html en la parte cuando hago el response

Comment: No sabria por donde empezar, pero seguro seguro, el codigo esta mal, por que indicators y slides solo van a tener informacion de la ultima fila leida.

Comment: entiendo que es un desarrollo asp.net mvc, no?  si es asi porque lo programas de es forma, porque no generas los datos en el action del controller y envias estos a la view

Comment: no es MVC es webpage razor, MVC no lo domino es por eso que esta así mi codigo

Comment: en el debugger, revisa la cadena que andas construyendo, mira en el HTML, te genera la ruta adecuada de la imagen? por cierto, indicators += indicators & "la cadena que andas generando", y de la misma manera con slides +=slides & "la cadena que vas generando" asi va generando la cadena, caso contrario solo estas definiendo lo mismo una y otra vez en ese do while. Saludos

Comment: hace un tiempo hice un tutorial sobre WebPages usando Razor utilizando C#, espero te sea de utilidad, aquí lo tienes http://www.slideshare.net/fredyfx/tutorial-ms-web-matrixv4

Answer (score 1):

No deberias acceder a los datos desde la `view`, es por medio del  `controller` y el `action` que consultas la db y devuelves un `model` a la `view`

Podrias definir una clase `model` como ser

```
Public Class CarouselViewModel
    Public Property Images As List(Of Imagen)
End Class

Public Class Imagen
    Public Property Nombre As String
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property Counter As Integer
End Class
```

Despues desde el `action` del controller devuelves el model a la view

```
Public Class xxController

   Public Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim model As New CarouselViewModel()
        model.Images = new List(Of Imagen)

        Dim cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("portal").ConnectionString

        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conexion
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE status='1' ORDER BY datecreate "
        conexion.Open()       

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While dr.Read()
            Dim img As New Imagen()
            img.Nombre = dr.GetString(3)
            img.Url = dr.GetString(1)
            img.Counter = i
            model.Images.Add(img)
            i= i + 1
        Loop

        dr.Close()
        conexion.Close()

        Return View(model)

   End Function

End Class
```

En la view defines la clase model y la recorres

```
@Model CarouselViewModel
@Code
   PageData("Title") = "Escriba el título aquí"
   Layout = "_Layout.vbhtml"

End Code
<div> 
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page-inner">
            <section class="section-white">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicadores -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            @For Each item In Model.Imagenes
                                <li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='@item.Counter'></li>"
                                <div class='item active'><img src='@item.Url' /><div class='carousel-caption'><h3>@item.Nombre</h3></div></div>"
                            End If
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- Controles -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Analiza como se realiza el `For Each` de la lista de imagenes que contiene el model, usas las propiedades para arman los tag html.
Es una Url lo que debes asignar el `src` de la imagen.